# Ayuda en Consulta de MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Veran estoy tratando de hacer una serie de ejercicios en MYSQL, usando la base de datos SAKILA, el problema que tengo, es un ejercicio en donde se me pide una consulta donde retorne el `id` de un cliente, la cantidad de peliculas no rentadas y el nombre de estas... Ya probe usando left y right join y me devuelve lo mismo...

```
SELECT R.customer_id, Data.total AS Cnt_No_Alquilo, F.title
FROM rental R 
LEFT JOIN inventory I ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id 
LEFT JOIN film F ON I.film_id = F.film_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT R.customer_id, count(R.rental_id) total 
from rental R
LEFT Join inventory I ON I.inventory_id = R.inventory_id
GROUP BY R.customer_id) Data ON R.customer_id = Data.customer_id
WHERE R.customer_id = 98
```

Comment: *me devuelve lo mismo* ... pero ¿qué es *lo mismo*? Para que te devuelva las filas que no cumplen están en la otra tabla del `JOIN` puedes usar `LEFT JOIN` pero agregando al `WHERE`  una condición como: `WHERE R.customer_id = 98 AND I.film_id IS NULL` . Lo que intentas hacer con esto: `INNER JOIN (SELECT R.customer_id, count(R.rental_id) total `  no lo veo del todo claro y puede que te fastidie los resultados. Faltan detalles en tu pregunta.

Comment: Osease ese codigo hace una consulta devolviendo el id del cliente y RETORNA LA CANTIDAD Y EL NOMBRE DE LA PELICULAS RENTADAS (Lo que quiero  es solo la cantidad y peliculas NO RENTADAS) bueno y la parte del `INNER JOIN (SELECT R.customer_id, count(R.rental_id) total` eso solo me sirve para copiar en columna la misma cantidad, sin perder el listado de los nombres, pero probare con lo que me recomendaste

Comment: Deberías de mostrarnos la estructura de tu tabla para de esta forma ayudarte, entre mas información puedas darnos, más facil será para la comunidad ayudarte, además, el uso de sentencias a las que tu le haces un JOIN son para unir o estructurar datos de multiples tablas en una sola consulta, pero para ello debería de haber un identificador que se relacione entre las mismas tablas.

Comment: Bueno la tabla que trato de hacer consta de 3 columnas, para que funcione se tomara el id de un cliente, conforme a ese id, esas columnas devolveran datos, la primera columna devuelve ese id del cliente, la segunda columna devuelve el total de peliculas no rentadas, y la tercera es una columna que enlista el nombre de estas peliculas...
Sobre lo del identificador, bueno, me baso en el diagrama Entidad-Relacion de Sakila, el clavo es que no se sacar aun datos con Left o Right join sin que el resultado me aparezca Empty...

Comment: Puedes subir un screenshot de la estructura de tu Base de Datos, por ello Cedano te sugirio mayor información a tu pregunta, porque realmente queda muy abierta.

Comment: Cuate es la base de datos Sakila, ya viene en MySQL por defecto, pero igual, he aqui el diagrama ![Diagrama Entidad-Relacion Sakila](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/images/SampleSakila.png).